# Looking for sufficient conditions for positive Fourier transforms

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am looking for some sufficient conditions for an even, continuous, nonnegative, non-increasing, non-convex function to be non-negative definite.  In other words
$$
\int_0^\infty f(x)\cos(x\omega) \, dx\ge 0, \quad   \omega \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
The function $f(x)=\exp(-x^{\alpha})[x^{\alpha} \log(x) + \delta/\alpha ]$, $\alpha\in(1,2)$, $\delta\ge 2$.  Note that for $\alpha\in(0,1)$, $f(x)$ is convex.
I have tried complex detour numerically (as in Tuck, E. O.: On positivity of Fourier transforms, Bull. Austral. Math. Soc., 74 (2006) 133–
138) – did not work out. It seems the imaginary part always increases around $0$.
I have tried Polya type conditions () - no luck either.
For $\alpha\in(0,1)$ everything works out as the function is convex.
Thank you in advance for any hints or references!

Comment: You can find a list of necessary conditions in [On the positivity of Fourier transforms](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.3155).

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, thank you, good read, I am seeking sufficient conditions though as I believe the function I am interested in is positive definite - cannot prove it rigorously but have some hand waving arguments

Comment: positive definite for all $\delta$ ?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, $\delta\ge 2$, I have edited the question, thank you

Comment: You did 11 edits in 2 days, please don't permanently edit your post. Edit 7 was changing "Sufficient" into "sufficient" and Edit 12 was the reverse edit, so it looks like artificially putting the post in the front list.

Comment: @YCor You give me too much credit, I just have OCD.  In my list, the posts appear according to the time of submission, apologies.

Comment: Your last edit is the kind of thing which @YCor was counselling against. Please stop doing this - the question itself is fine, please just trust people to look at it as and when they find time

Comment: @YemonChoi, yes, I am trying, sorry

Comment: @mathworker21, someone else edited it to be capital, I have changed it back to small, then thought whoever did it is an administrator of some sort and  may get offended - changed it back to capital and got accused of cheating the system;))). I do not mind if you change it back to small. Also it seems that people started to offer me  necessary conditions - which are nice but not what asked for

Answer (score 16):

*please show me how to prove for $|\omega|>20$*

With great pleasure. We shall just show that $F(y)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x^a}x^a\log x\cos(yx)\,dx>0$ for large enough $y>0$. Note that $\cos(yx)=\Re e^{iyx}$, so we have the real part of a contour integral from $0$ to $+\infty$ of $e^{-z^a}z^a\log z e^{iyz}\,dz$. The integrand oscillates like crazy on the line, so we would like to move the contour up to get less oscillation. *Ideally* we would like to have a curve $\Gamma$ parameterized by $z(t)$ so that $\Re \left[e^{-z^a}z^a\log z e^{iyz}z'(t) \right] \ge 0$ everywhere on $\Gamma$. If we can do it, it would be the end of the story. However, for the integral in question it is, clearly, impossible (without the extra $1$ or $2$, the Fourier transform has zero integral, so it cannot be positive everywhere), so we'll settle for less: the integral over the "head part" of the contour will have relatively large positive real part and the tail will be small.

We will use the same curve $\Gamma$ that is normally used to prove that the Fourier transform of $e^{-|x|^a}$ is non-negative, namely, the curve $z(x)=x+i\xi(x)$, $x>0$, where $\xi(x)$ satisfies $(x+i\xi)^a=g+iyx$, $\xi,g\in\mathbb R$. This will make $e^{-z^a}e^{iyz}$ real positive on $\Gamma$. Note that $\xi$ is well-defined and continuous in $x$ for $1\le a<2$ and $\xi(x)\asymp x^{2-a}$ at $+\infty$, so this change of the contour is legitimate.

On $\Gamma$, we have $e^{-z^a}e^{iyz}=e^{-H}$ where $H=g+y\xi$. Differentiating the identity defining $\Gamma$, we get $az^{a-1}(1+i\xi_x)=g_x+iy$, so
$$
H_x=g_x+y\xi_x=\Re [(g_x+iy)(1-i\xi_x)]=\Re[az^{a-1}|1+\xi_x|^2]>0 
$$
for $z$ in the first quadrant, so $H$ is strictly increasing.

We now want to evaluate
$$
\Re\int_{\Gamma} e^{-H}z^a\log z\,dz=\int_{\Gamma} \Re\left[\frac{z^{a+1}}{a+1}\left(\log z-\frac 1{a+1}\right)\right]d(-e^{-H})\,.
$$
To do it, we will switch to polar coordinates $z=Re^{i\theta}$. Notice that the equation for $\Gamma$ becomes $R^a\sin(a\theta)=yR\cos\theta$. Since $\theta\mapsto \frac{\sin(a\theta)}{\cos\theta}$ increases from $0$ to $+\infty$ as $\theta$ runs from $0$ to $\pi/2$, the curve $\Gamma$ intersects every circumference centered at $0$ only once, so the radius $R$ is a legitimate parameter on $\Gamma$.

We also have $\Re [z^a\bar z]=\Re[(x-i\xi)(g+iyx)]=x(g+y\xi)=xH$, so
$$
H=R^a\frac{\cos((a-1)\theta)}{\cos\theta}
$$
Now come a couple of observations. The first one is that
$$
\sin(a\theta)=\sin((a-1)\theta)\cos\theta+\cos((a-1)\theta)\sin\theta
$$
and
$$
-\sin((a-1)\theta)\cos\theta+\cos((a-1)\theta)\sin\theta=\sin((2-a)\theta)>0
$$
for $\theta\in[0.\frac{\pi}2]$. Hence
$$
R^a\cos((a-1)\theta)\sin\theta\le R^a\sin(a\theta)=yR\cos\theta\le 2R^a\cos((a-1)\theta)\sin\theta\,.
$$
Juxtaposing this with the polar formula for $H$, we see that
$H\sin\theta\le yR\le 2H\sin\theta$ on $\Gamma$.

The second observation is that $\sin(a\theta)\le 1$, so for $R\in[0,1]$, we have $\cos\theta\le\frac 1y$, i.e., $\theta\in[\theta_0,\frac\pi 2]$ where $\theta_0=\arccos\frac 1y$ is quite close to $\frac\pi 2$ for large $y$.

Now we are ready to look at the real part of $\frac{z^{a+1}}{a+1}\left(\log z-\frac 1{a+1}\right)$ when $R\le 1$. It is
$$
\frac{R^{a+1}}{a+1}\left[\cos((a+1)\theta)\left(\log R-\frac 1{a+1}\right)-\theta\sin((a+1)\theta)\right]\,.
$$
Note that $(a+1)\theta\in [2\theta_0,\frac{3\pi}2)$, so as soon as $\theta_0\ge\pi/4$ ($y>\sqrt 2$), the cosine is negative. Thus we can ignore $\log R<0$, which leaves us with the expression
$$
-\cos((a+1)\theta)\frac 1{a+1}-\theta\sin((a+1)\theta)
$$
on $[\theta_0,\frac {\pi}2]$. Taking the derivative, we see that it is increasing in $\theta$, so $\theta=\theta_0$ is the worst case. Again, it can easily be verified that this expression is greater than, say, $c(a)=\frac 1{2(a+1)}$ if $\theta_0$ is close enough to $\frac\pi 2$. Taking into account the bound $H\le yR/\sin\theta_0=:H_1R$ on $[0,1]$ and noting that for $R=1$, we have $H=\Re[z^a]+y\xi\ge -1+y\sin\theta_0=:H_0$, we immediately conclude that
$$
\int_{\Gamma:R<1}\dots d(-e^{-H})\ge c(a)\int_0^{H_0/H_1}\frac {R^{a+1}}{a+1}H_1e^{-H_1R}\,dR
$$
For large $y$, we have $H_0\approx H_1\approx y$ (see the accurate estimates above), so the whole integral is about
$$
\frac{c(a)y}{a+1}\int_0^1 R^{a+1}e^{-yR}\,dR\approx \frac{c(a)}{a+1}y^{-a-1}\int_0^\infty r^{a+1}e^{-r}\,dr
$$
i.e., we have just power decay in $y$ here.

On the other hand, since $R\le 2H/y=R(H)$ all the way through, we have
$$
\left|\int_{\Gamma: R>1}\dots d(-e^{-H})\right|\le\frac 1{a+1}\int_{H_0}^\infty R(H)^{a+1}\sqrt{\left(\log R(H)+\frac 1{a+1}\right)^2+\frac{\pi^2}4} \,e^{-H}\,dH\,,
$$
which decays exponentially in $y$, so the whole integral is positive for large $y$. I leave the accurate estimates of the minimal $y$ for which it works to you. $y>20$ is certainly enough, but I won't be suprised if one can push it down to $y>10$.

I'm still struggling with small $y$... :-( Meanwhile, feel free to ask questions if something is unclear.

Comment: the proof is awesome, I am struggling to find a way to evaluate $y$ numerically. I believe it should be $y$ which makes the second integral positive. What is $H_0$?

Comment: @TanyaVladi Sorry, forgot to write: $H_0=-1+y\sin\theta_0$ (the lower bound for $H$ at the moment of escape from the unit circle).

Comment: got it, thank you. Just a follow up question, it seems using your method one can get a lower bound on  $F(y)$, it is possible to estimate when the global minimum occur? the number of zeros of $F(y)$

Comment: I have run numerics. Basically I find points on the $\Gamma$ by solving $R^{\alpha-1}\sin(\alpha\theta)=\cos(\theta)y$ for fixed $y$ and $\alpha$- get pairs of $(x,\xi)$. As you can imagine $\xi$ is an increasing function of  $x$.  I have noticed that large $y$ do not work as real part of ${z^{\alpha+1}\over \alpha+1}$ $\{\log(z)-{1\over \alpha+1}\}$ is negative for large $\xi$. On the other hand tiny $y$s work perfectly as the real part is positive, What am I missing?

Comment: @TanyaVladi You are probably missing the logic of this proof: The real part for the large $y$ is negative once the curve leaves the unit disk and the second integral estimates the *negative contribution*, so it has to be subtracted. The positive contribution comes from the part of the curve in the unit disk, which is bounded from below by the first integral. The point is that for large $y$ the first (positive) integral decays in a power (in $y$) fashion while the second one decays exponentially, so the positive contribution wins. I'm getting a cutoff at around $y=8.5$ uniformly in $a$.

Comment: I think I got the logic, I am just trying to adjust the proof ti my original function. I actually do not see how you got the expression under square root.  "On the other hand, since $R\le 2H/y=R(H)$ all the way through, we have"
$$
\left|\int_{\Gamma: R>1}\dots d(-e^{-H})\right|\le\frac 1{a+1}\int_{H_0}^\infty R(H)^{a+1}\sqrt{\left(\log R(H)+\frac 1{a+1}\right)^2+\frac{\pi^2}4} \,e^{-H}\,dH\,,
$$ .  Can you please drop a hint or two?

Comment: @TanyaVladi The expression under the square root is just the upper bound on $|\log z-\frac 1{a+1}|$ where $z$ is in the first quadrant with $1\le |z|\le R(H)$: the real part of $\log z$ is at most $\log R(H)$ and the imaginary part (the argument of $z$) is between $0$ and $\pi/2$, hence the sum of squares. I added $\frac 1{a+1}$ instead of subtracting for safety: $|a-b|\le A+b$ for $0\le a<A$, $b>0$ but not necessarily less than $|A-b|$. That's all.

Comment: @fedja, how do you get $8.5$? why did you remove the term $\delta \exp(-x^{\alpha})/\alpha$, it seems the term is needed to make sure the function is positive for smaller values (greater than 1 and apparently smaller than 8,5)

Comment: @Vova 1) Just by numerically comparing the integrals in the estimates. If you do it by hand with rough bounds, you get something like $12$. 2) Because I still cannot use it efficiently: even with that term (that is, indeed, needed for the full range, as I mentioned in the very beginning), I can prove only the same result (large $y$ only), so I just wanted to attract one's attention to the fact that in this regime it is not necessary.

Comment: @fedja thank you, can you estimated the global minimum?

Comment: @Vova Yes. but the estimate is not good enough to be beaten by $e^{-y^2/4}$. Of course, what I proved is enough to show that the FT is positive if $\delta$ is sufficiently large, but "sufficiently" is currently way above the required $\delta=2$.

Comment: @fedja, thank you for your comments. How about combining two approaches. The one from Tuck's paper requires convexity for the real part of the function and positive and decreasing imaginary part of the function, which is true (according to my numerical studies) for $≥1$ (can be smaller) and contour $+0.01$ for any $$. It seems with your approach the real part of the function is positive for any $$ and $\ge1$. I cannot formally prove that though.  I do understand that $x=R\cos(\theta)$ and when $y$ is large $R>1$

Comment: @TanyaVladi  "the real part of the function is positive for any $y$ and $x\ge 1$". Hmm... That is quite doubtful because, adjusting $y$, we can get any $z$ with fixed real part to lie on the curve. I'll look into it though my free time is limited :-)

Comment: @fedja, sorry I meant $x<1$.  The idea is to split the range of $x$ into $[0,1]$ and $[1,\infty]$. You approach works for the first part and Tuck's for the second

Comment: @fedja, by the way my original problem/question was about showing that Fourier of $\exp(-|x|^{\alpha})/\alpha^2$, $x\in R$ decays as a function of $1<\alpha<2$,  for any $\omega$. By taking derivative- I made a problem more complicated as it seems

Answer (score 3):

This can be very complicated, so I will only give a reference which contains many highly non-trivial results of this sort:

MR0428382 J. V. Linnik and  I. V. Ostrovskiĭ,  Decomposition of random variables and vectors. Translated from the Russian. Translations of Mathematical Monographs, Vol. 48. American Mathematical Society, Providence, R. I., 1977.

Look especially in the chapter which is called Necessary conditions for $I_0$,
I think it is Chapter IV.

Comment: I have the book and checked it. Are you implying that my function is of Levy Hinchin representation? I do not see it, can you please drop another hint?

Comment: I only answered the first sentence in your message, not about this specific function. I do not claim that your function has a Levy Hinchin representation.

Comment: Change of contour should work (as I commented in your other post, it *does* work if you care only about $|\omega|>20$) but it seems rather delicate because the function has a zero in the first quadrant and treating it properly in the full range requires a lot of extra care. On the side note, asking slight variations of the same question several times in a row is usually frowned upon, though you seem lucky so far :-)

Comment: I am not an expert and do not know what extra care I need. I have done some numerical work and was discouraged by the results. I read the paper , but could not get the nice closed form analytical expression for Im or Re parts of a complex detour of the function.  As for asking the same question- the question does not look difficult for a mathematician. I am surprised I did not get an answer so far - I blame myself for not being able to ask it correctly, hence I iterate.

Comment: @TanyaVladi It isn't easy if you want to get a proof in the full range and do not want to settle for anything less, as it seems to be the case (otherwise I would post my $|\omega|>20$ solution long ago). Your question has been crystal clear all the time. Just give people some time to figure it out. :-) Of course, there is no explicit formula for anything here but it is not what makes it tricky. The real issue is the unpleasant behavior of the argument of $1+z\log z$ in the upper half-plane and I'm still struggling with it in the case of small $\omega$.

Comment: @fedja, please show me how to prove for $|\omega|>20$. I can show  it is positive for small $\omega$

Comment: @fedja, I found the following paper   Luo, S. L. and Zhang, Z. M.: Estimating the first zero of a characteristic function,
C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris, Ser. I 338 (2004), 203–206. . . Basically I can find $\tau$, such that my transform is positive for all  arguments less than that. It is, according to the paper,   $\Delta(\alpha,p)=\pi/(2M_p(\alpha))^{1/p}$.$\Delta(\alpha,p)$ is small, around 1, but it is a good start

Comment: @TanyaVladi Done (large $\omega$)

Answer (score 2):

How about the following reference T. Gneiting, Criteria of Po´lya type for radial positive definite functions, Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 129 (2001), 2309–2318. I have plotted the results for 6th derivative all numeric but it seems working,

Comment: Looks very interesting. So what particular $k,l,\alpha$ do you suggest?