# How to prove the Fourier transform of $e^{-x^p}$ is positive

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I wonder how to prove that

$$\int_0^\infty\exp(-x^p)\cos(tx)\,dt\geq 0, \quad \frac{1}{2}<p<1.$$

This conclusion is used in the answer to another question here
[Looking for sufficient conditions for positive Fourier transforms](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365619/looking-for-sufficient-conditions-for-positive-fourier-transforms)

Comment: That's due to Pólya if I remember correctly: integrate by parts twice to get $\int_0^\infty [\exp(-x^p)]'' t^{-2} (1 - \cos t x) dx$.

Comment: Did you use Bochner's theorem? One needs to show the square matrix $[f(t_i-t_j)]$ has all positive eigenvalues for every finite subset $\{t_1,t_2,...,t_n\}$ and all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, where $f(t)=e^{-|t|^p}$.

Comment: this is answered at https://mathoverflow.net/a/228488/11260

Comment: This has $also$ been answered here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/256526/positivity-of-certain-fourier-transform and in my answer you have a ridiculously simple probabilistic explanation of why positivity is lost if $p>2$.